# ESP32: shared variable between tasks

Tags: multithreading, esp32, producer-consumer

I would like to implement a producer/consumer task on ESP32. For that, there are two tasks: the first task reads the input through I2C and stores those in a queue; the second tasks takes the value from the queue. Although, the producer provides the data continuously, therefore cannot be on hold, meanwhile the the consumer task is relatively slow as that includes file-management.
For that reason, I have two queues, so during the consumer taking the values from one of the queues, the consumer fills the other queue. For that I intend to implement a kind of semaphore providing the info for tasks which queue they supposed to use.

During the execution, the following error message recieved:

```
ELF file SHA256: f835c00085624c05

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13104
load:0x40080400,len:3036
entry 0x400805e4

assert failed: xQueueGenericSend queue.c:820 (pxQueue)


Backtrace: 0x40083585:0x3ffb4d80 0x400890c9:0x3ffb4da0 0x4008e10d:0x3ffb4dc0 0x400898ce:0x3ffb4ef0 0x400d1444:0x3ffb4f30
```

Here is the relevant code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "esp_task_wdt.h"

TaskHandle_t Task1_f;
TaskHandle_t Task2_f;
void Task1code( void * pvParameters );
void Task2code( void * pvParameters );
static volatile QueueHandle_t queue;

enum semaphore_t {INSENDING, INRECEIVING, IDLE};
static volatile semaphore_t queue_semaphore;

void setup() {
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    Task1code,                /* Task function. */
    "Task1 - producer",       /* name of task. */
    10000,                    /* Stack size of task */
    NULL,                     /* parameter of the task */
    1,                        /* priority of the task */
    &Task1_f,                 /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
    0);                       /* pin task to core 0 */                  

  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    Task2code,                /* Task function. */
    "Task2 - consumer",       /* name of task. */
    10000,                    /* Stack size of task */
    NULL,                     /* parameter of the task */
    2,                        /* priority of the task */
    &Task2_f,                 /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
    1);                       /* pin task to core 1 */  

  queue = xQueueCreate(256, sizeof(uint8_t));
  queue_semaphore = INSENDING;

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
}


void Task1code( void * pvParameters ){
  uint8_t l_counter = 0;
  Serial.printf("%s running on core %d\n", "Task1code", xPortGetCoreID());
  
  for(;;){    

    if(l_counter<100){
      xQueueSend(queue, &l_counter, portMAX_DELAY);
      l_counter++;
    }else if(queue_semaphore==INSENDING){
      queue_semaphore=INRECEIVING;
    }else if(queue_semaphore==IDLE){
      queue_semaphore=INSENDING;
      l_counter=0;
    }

    esp_task_wdt_reset();

    delay(5000);
  }
}

void Task2code( void * pvParameters ){
  uint8_t l_counter = 0;

  Serial.printf("%s running on core %d\n", "Task2code", xPortGetCoreID());

  for(;;){
    if(queue_semaphore==INRECEIVING){
       while(uxQueueSpacesAvailable(queue)!=256){
         xQueueReceive(queue, &l_counter, portMAX_DELAY);
         //...
       }

      queue_semaphore=IDLE;
    }

    esp_task_wdt_reset();

    delay(3000);
  }
}

void loop() {
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

Note: The code is simplified

I am not so sure whether FreeRTOS binary semaphore or mutex would solve the problem, because the producer task cannot be on hold.

Comment: I only see one queue being created. As expected, it has a fixed size. How do you handle the queue filling up since the producer runs faster than the consumer? Having two queues will not fix the problem. Instead, you will simply fill up both queues. Consider either slowing the producer to match the consumer speed or implementing a sampling algorithm.

Comment: @JimRogers you are right, I over simplified the code, although it does no change the fact to much: the above example throws the reported problem which is still blocking problem for me... Why the assert is raised?

Comment: The error message is poorly designed because it does not describe what was asserted. Could it be that you are attempting to write beyond the end of the queue?

Comment: If you open the source file `queue.c` for your version of ESP IDF on line 820 then you'll quickly discover why it's asserting. A few hints: you're creating a queue on line `queue = xQueueCreate(256, sizeof(uint8_t));` but you never check if this succeeded or not. You may not have enough heap for a queue :)

Comment: Finally I figured it out and actually it is a childish mistake... There is nothing wrong with the queue although that is created after the two tasks have been launched; so modifying the setup() it works.